# Method equivalent for @InjectMocks

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

What is method equivalent for the following:

```
@Mock
MyType1 myType1;

@Autowired
@InjectMocks
MyType2 myType2;
```

I can replace `@Mock` with `mock(MyType1.class)`.

But how can I replace `@InjectMocks` with a method call? Something like this:

```
injectMocks(MyType2.class)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why using `Autowired` in your junit test? Since you are mocking the dependencies for `MyType2` you must know its concreate implementation when you write your test.

Then you don't need and shouldn't use Spring or any injection framework to create the instance of `MyType2` that you want to test. Create it directly in your test initialization! I know that after some years of using IoC frameworks, it's difficult to write `myType2 = new MyType2Impl(mock(myType1.class))` but it will really makes your tests simpler, and faster (because no application context to build).
E.g.:

```
@Before
public void setup() {
  myType1 = mock(MyType1.class);
  myType2 = new MyType2Impl(myType1);
}
```

But if you really want to use IoC in your junit tests, use [springockito](http://www.springockito.org/) has suggested by Brice, and build your mock `MyType1` in your application context.

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: @jonney IoC = Inversion of control, see https://martinfowler.com/bliki/InversionOfControl.html

Comment: this should have been a comment rather than an answer as it does not really answer the question: how to call `@InjectMocks` manually?

Answer (score 18):

There is no public API in Mockito for mock injection. Plus as this annotation is mostly driven on the way things are laid out in a test, it is fairly related to the initialization phase of the test.

Though it might change at some point in the future.

However Mockito annotated fields can be initialized either by the `MockitoJUnitRunner` or by `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks()`. They both create mock instances and perform injection.

Also I see in your code that you are using `@Autowired` - hence spring stuff, probably  configured via XML. `@InjectMocks` wasn't really developed to work with other dependency injection frameworks, as the development was driven by unit test use cases, not integration tests.

You might want to take a look at [springockito](https://github.com/springockito/springockito), which is another project that tries to ease Mockito mock creation in Spring.

Hope that helps

Comment: The link is dead.

Comment: @TarunMaganti I updated the link. Alhough it seems there is now several forks of springockito, I think this one is the official one, but check before using it ;)